# Sensor Indicator for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: indicator, sensors

Is there any repo for stable version of indicator-sensor ubuntu 14.04?
Or are there any other alternatives to indicator-sensor for ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the indicator-sensor package, but for other alternatives you might take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available

Answer (score 2):

There's their ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors-daily
Update software source and try installing it.

Comment: thanks. but i was hoping for a stable release or some alternative, as daily builds in general known crash often.

Comment: Judging by the update frequency I don't think this is the same as other 'daily' PPA repos.

Answer (score 1):

I manually installed the indicator-sensors package for Ubuntu 13.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 and it works fine. So, this can be a temporary solution until the package for Ubuntu 14.04 will be available.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not available for 14.04
[image: Here is the build info for 14.04]